# Possibility of Groupby in Pandas for cross-group Matching

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to match persons to different groups at the time. While I have an implementation currently that does the job, it gets extremely slow for larger DataFrames. I was looking in implementing a groupby function to find the group memberships of each person, but could not find a solution. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Example of how the DataFrame looks like:

```py
d = {"person": [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,5,2,1,7],
     "group":  [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(d)

    person  group
0   1       1
1   2       1
2   3       1
3   4       2
4   5       2
5   6       2
6   1       3
7   5       3
8   2       3
9   1       4
10  7       4
```

The (working) code currently looks as follows:

```py
for g in df.group.unique():

    df_g = df.loc[df.group == g]

    for p in df_g.person.unique():

        print(df.loc[df.person == p].group.unique()) # <-- the thing I care about.


[1 3 4]
[1 3]
[1]
[2]
[2 3]
[2]
[1 3 4]
[2 3]
[1 3]
[1 3 4]
[4]
```

As said, the code above is extremely slow (it needs to loop through many groups, and even more persons). Would it be possible to perform the same operation via groupby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) for new column filled by unique values:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('person')['group'].transform('unique')
print (df)
    person  group        new
0        1      1  [1, 3, 4]
1        2      1     [1, 3]
2        3      1        [1]
3        4      2        [2]
4        5      2     [2, 3]
5        6      2        [2]
6        1      3  [1, 3, 4]
7        5      3     [2, 3]
8        2      3     [1, 3]
9        1      4  [1, 3, 4]
10       7      4        [4]
```

Comment: 1 min too slow :-)

Comment: Great, this is almost exactly what I was looking for. This should work for further analysis. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Using `unique` with `reindex(df.person)`

```
df.groupby('person')['group'].unique().reindex(df.person)
Out[1410]: 
person
1    [1, 3, 4]
2       [1, 3]
3          [1]
4          [2]
5       [2, 3]
6          [2]
1    [1, 3, 4]
5       [2, 3]
2       [1, 3]
1    [1, 3, 4]
7          [4]
Name: group, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['all_groups'] = df.groupby('person').group.transform('unique')
```